# Date automatically modified to something else

Tags: excel, vba

Date changing from 11/09/2019 to 25/09/2019 with no apparent reason

Currently working on Excel 2010, I've tried to set my cell and range format to short date (dd/mm/yyyy) and even with number format.

```vb
        While Not (workingDay(Date + compteur, ws_non_ouvres))
            compteur = compteur + 1
        Wend
        Set ws_cc_working = wb_centre_de_charges.Worksheets("J+1")
        ws_cc_working.Activate
        Range("C3").Select
        If (WeekdayName(Weekday(Date + compteur, vbMonday)) Like "samedi") Then
            compteur = compteur + 2
        End If
        ws_cc_working.Cells(3, 3).Value = Format((Date + compteur), "dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
        compteur = compteur + 1
```

Here's the code. First, we do a loop to verify that the current date is a working day. Then, I set the worksheet and then select the Range C3, where the date should be written. 
Then, we verify that the date isn't a saturday, skipping two days if true (so it becomes monday).

Finally, we set the value of the cell "C3",  (3,3), to today's date plus the counter.

I hope this help, sorry for my lack of English

I don't understand why excel is modifying the date from 11/09 to 25/09. The result should be 11/09 and I'm not doing anything that occurs with the value.

Thanks for answers and your help.

Comment: Debug your code with F8, step by step, to see in the loop what is changing.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but using numeric weekdays instead of language-specific `WeekdayName` would make the code more portable/robust.

Comment: Using the debug mode and some glorious Debug.Print I can assume that the value IS NOT modified in the code. However, it changes when the sub ends

Comment: `ws_cc_working.Cells(3, 3).Value = Format((Date + compteur), "dd\/mm\/yyyy\")` this line modifies `C3`. If `compteur`is equal to 14, then today +14 = 25/09/2019

Comment: Thing is, the date is correctly set. It goes 10/09, 11/09, 12/09 ... and for some reason I can't explain, when I select the final sheet, it goes 10/09, 25/09, 12/09 ?

Comment: @LucasM it looks like the code you're showing us is living inside some parent loop block (why else would you increment `compteur` after writing the offset date to C3?) ...is there an outer loop? If so, how many iterations is that outer loop doing?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid doing math with `Date` values, prefer to use the specialized `DateTime` functions instead. What `compteur` stands for would be less ambiguous if it were a `offsetDays`.

The current date isn't going to change between calls to the `VBA.DateTime.Date` property - might as well call it just once, and keep its value with a meaningful local identifier.

```
Dim currentDate As Date
currentDate = VBA.DateTime.Date
```

`While...Wend` is an archaic construct, too - best replace it with `Do While...Loop`.

```
Do While Not workingDay(DateAdd("d", offsetDays, currentDate))
    offsetDays = offsetDays + 1
Loop
```

Avoid code that will break if executed on a computer with different regional settings:

> ```
>     If (WeekdayName(Weekday(Date + compteur, vbMonday)) Like "samedi") Then
>         compteur = compteur + 2
>     End If
> ```

Consider using the built-in constants instead - note that if you compute the weekday with the week starting on `vbSunday`, then the function will return `vbSaturday` (7) for "samedi", and the regional-settings -sensitive string representation of that weekday no longer matters:

```
If (Weekday(Date + compteur, vbSunday) = vbSaturday) Then
    offsetDays = offsetDays + 2
End If
```

And so we get to the cell-writing part:

> ```
>     ws_cc_working.Cells(3, 3).Value = Format((Date + compteur), "dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
>     compteur = compteur + 1
> ```

You're writing a formatted `String` into the cell: if Excel needs to understand the date as a `Date`, that's playing with fire. Instead, write the actual `Date` value you want, and use `Range.NumberFormat` to make its string representation match your liking:

```
ws_cc_working.Cells(3, 3).Value = DateAdd("d", offsetDays, currentDate)
ws_cc_working.Cells(3, 3).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

offsetDays = offsetDays + 1
```

Treating dates as strings leaves Excel trying to be smart about what was written in the cell, and sometimes it gets it wrong. Treating dates as dates should "just work".

Note:

> *Then, I set the worksheet and then select the Range C3, where the date should be written*

You don't need to `Select` anything to write in a cell. If the cell doesn't need to be selected/active when the macro finishes, consider removing `Worksheet.Activate` and `Range.Select` calls and leaving the user's current selection alone.

Comment: Many thanks for this, as I'm Learning vba by myself, I may have "bad vba manners", I'll change my code with that and I'll see if it helps, thanks again.